# Matplotlib ytick's absolute value

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

In matplotlib, how can I use absolute value in the yticks?

For example, 100, 50, 0, 50, 100, 150.

[image: Matplotlib]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the current ticks using get_yticks, modify that and then use set_yticklabels. See the example below.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import trunc
a = np.random.rand(100)*30-20

plt.figure()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(np.arange(len(a)), a)

ticks =  ax.get_yticks()

# set labels to absolute values and with integer representation
ax.set_yticklabels([int(abs(tick)) for tick in ticks])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is even better.

Comment: How can I get rid of the zeros and the decimal points? Like 10 instead of 10.0?

Comment: Note that the ticks are not always populated until the figure is drawn.  In some cases you have to call `fig.canvas.draw()` to draw the figure and populate the tick labels.

Answer (score 2):

Since `ax.get_yticks()` returns `numpy.ndarray` object, it's possible to use `abs` function directly on it, which leads to even neater solution:

```py
ax.set_yticklabels(abs(ax.get_yticks()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could manually replace the y-axis tick labels.

For example:

```
ax.set_yticks(range(-100, 200, 50))
ax.set_yticklabels([abs(y) for y in range(-100, 200, 50)])
```